# Stop users filling out form multiple times

Tags: html

I implemented a simple html-form with some input boxes and a button. As soon as a user clicks on the button, the value is sent to the server and stored in a MySQL - DB. I use html client-side and php server-side if that matters.
[EDIT: Furthermore, the users are not logged-in while they click on the "submit" button. I intend to create an anonymous survey.]

My question: How can I prevent a user to fill out the form more than once?

Thanks much,

enne

Comment: A bunch of ways - cookies/session variables or just do a search in the database and do not commit the INSERT if the user's information already exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, are you just trying to prevent the user from clicking the submit button twice? A simple bit of javascript can disable the button as soon as it is clicked:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').disabled = true;
```

Or are you attempting to prevent a user coming back at a later time and filling in the form again?  In this case, if the user is authenticated, then it is very easy, as I'm sure you know - just store the user ID with every submission, and ensure the user does not already have a submission in the database before accepting a new one.

However, if the user is not authenticated, then there is no 100% effective way of preventing multiple submissions.  As mentioned by NCoder, you could check for IP address uniqueness, but this will fail in two situations:

1. For all users behind a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), and therefore sharing the same IP, only one of them will be able to submit your form.  The first user will indeed be prevented from resubmitting, but it will also prevent all subsequent users on the same NAT from using your form **at all**.  There are probably mitigations you could put in place - for instance, allow up to x submissions from the same IP, where x is a number high enough to cope with NATed users, but low enough to prevent your results being skewed too far by a determined attacker.
2. For users with dynamic IP addresses, this method will not be effective once their IP address has changed.

Another option would be to store a cookie on the user's machine once the form has been submitted, but the user can trivially work around this by clearing their cookies and/or using a different browser.

Depending on your specific situation - for instance, if data gathered by the form is not critical, and you are just trying to prevent casual resubmissions - then either of the above approaches could work (I would favor cookies for simplicity).

But, the only foolproof solution to your problem is to only allow authenticated users to submit your form.

Comment: I guess the thing with the IP-address is a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: @enne87 — Why are you guessing that when Mike spent two paragraphs about how it would fail?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is log successful submissions in a database with IP Addresses.

Then you can purge it daily, weekly, whatever, or never.

You'll then be able to prevent and even hide forms that they've already completed.

Since you're already using a database and PHP just create a field for IP_Address in your database.

Then do this:

```
<?

$IP_ADDRESS = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//where you're inserting your record, just check to see if a record already 
//exists in the database with that IP Address

?>
```

Comment: This is a pretty bad approach, because many users are behind NAT.

Comment: It really depends on his "users" ... it's a quick solution and it may be good for him based on what he's trying to do.

Comment: @NCoder Thanks for indicating not only what to do, but how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing something on the server side. A simple approach would be to wrap your form in a conditional statement that checks whether or not the user has already submitted the form. But without some more specifics, I won't be able to help you much further than that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to check to see if the email address is already on file.

With this option you would probably want to do an email validation where they click to verify in an email their account is valid.

So you would store all submissions but require they be validated by email address, with a limit of 1 record per email address.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to answer this, but I'm going to try anyway.

**If the users submitting this form are logged in (best case)**
When form is submitted, along with your form data, add a DB field specifying that the particular user has submitted the form.

All that would be needed is an integer 1 (default) = has not submitted the form and 2 = has already submitted the form.

Each time you process the form, select that field for the user and you will know right away. The other advantage to this approach is that you can apply any other condition that you need in the future.

**If the users submitting this form are not logged in**
You've got few options here. The best may be creating a cookie that they have submitted the form then doing `if (isset($_COOKIE['form'])) { echo "You've already submitted the form, sucks to be you." }`

Answer (score 0):

**i had this issue and all i did was add this few lines of code**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['form_submitted']))
    {
        die('You have already submitted the form.');
    }
    else
    {
        #submitted form code here
        $_SESSION['form_submitted'] = TRUE;
    }
}

?>
```